# case insensitive unordered_map<string, int>

Tags: c++, string, stl, std, unordered-map

How can I create a case-insensitive `unordered_map<string, int>`?
Does overriding `key_equal` is sufficient or I also need to update `hasher`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hasher needs to be updated as well, because the default hash algorithm [does not produce identical hash code for strings that differ only in the case of their symbols](http://ideone.com/S7pW1u) - an essential property of hash code function intended to work with case-insensitive strings.

```
std::string s1 = "Hello";
std::string s2 = "hello";
std::hash<std::string> hash_fn;

size_t hash1 = hash_fn(s1);
size_t hash2 = hash_fn(s2);

std::cout << hash1 << '\n';
std::cout << hash2 << '\n';
```

This shows different values on ideone:

```
101669370
3305111549
```

Comment: Your answer is right in general, but we are talking about `std::hash<Key>` function here. So your answer may be wrong depending how `std::hash<Key>` works for strings (which I have no idea)!

Comment: @MBZ It would not make sense to alter the `std::hash` for `string`s to pay no attention to character case: the function would be more expensive in terms of CPU use, and would result in more collisions, too.

Comment: you could just make all the strings lowercase before you hash them

Comment: @aaronman That would defeat the purpose: OP does not want to do it externally to the hash map, he wants the map do it for him.

Comment: I mean you could just write a wrapper